# What's the meaning of "five past dreams"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "five past dreams" in the following [lyrics](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/c/chris_de_burgh/five_past_dreams.html):

> **It's five past dreams**, I should be home asleep,
>   But I just want to keep this moment alive, it's just you and I,
>   ...
>   ...
>   **It's five past dreams**, the world is waking up, just like I should
>   Have done a long time ago, maybe I'm slow, I just didn't know,
>   That the saviour of my heart is right here

Comment: The interpretation of lyrics is off topic for this site.

Comment: @coleopterist it's not

Comment: "Five past dreams" is likely a poetic way of saying "it's late."  Perhaps the speaker of the words has spent the entire night with the one he loves, talking and enjoying one her company.  The speaker is sort of chiding himself for not realizing sooner that the "savior of his heart" is right there with him.  Just as the world is waking up from sleep, he too is waking up to the realization that he loves the woman he is with.  (Obviously, the speaker could be a woman, and the savior a man!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an example of [*synecdoche*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy#Synecdoche) or [*metonymy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) where "dreams" is used to stand for "the time for sleep".

The construction is similar to "five past eleven" (11:05pm) but the time is simply "when I should be in bed asleep and dreaming".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simply a pun, like if dream was an hour.